# Save canvas img with droidscript

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, droidscript

OK so I am aware of the traditional HTML5 ways of saving a canvas img as a `png`, however my project is a DroidScript app and window location doesn't work and there is no server side to post process the img on a server and download it.

My question is how would one get the img to save using the DroidScript api probably using app.WriteFile.

I've tried generating the img with `var img = app.CreateImage` and then saving it with `img.Save` but the img isn't successfully generated, I've also tried converting it to a blob using `canvas.toBlob` and using `app.WriteFile` but the png is broken... same with canvas.toDataURL as well.

Both conversions fail with `app.WriteFile` and `app.CreateFile` which are the only solutions that seem to actually save the file at all. I've also tried using JavaScript's FileReader to do the conversions with no success...

I believe I am simply doing the order of operations incorrectly or using the wrong properties.

I don't have all of the versions of code that I've tried but here is the latest version that is generating a broken `png`.

```
app.toImage = function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function readSuccess(e) { 
    var img = e.target.result;
    var file = app.CreateFile('/sdcard/Download/t.png', "rw");
              
        uint8ArrayNew = new Uint8Array(img);
    file.WriteData(uint8ArrayNew, "Bytes");
    file.Close();
        };
        win.canvas.toBlob(function(b) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(b);
        });
}
    }
```

EDIT... this code saves the base64 data url inside of the file as a string which can be validated to show the correct image, however the file still appears as broken in a file browser

```
app.toImage = function(){
        
        var img = win.canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64;");
        
        
        var reader  = new FileReader();

          reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            // preview.src = reader.result;
            app.WriteFile('/sdcard/Download/t.png', reader.result);
          }, false);
                win.canvas.toBlob(function(b) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(b);
                });
 }
    }
```

This is the file contents

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Paste into this tool and i get the correct image

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

How do i save it as an actual png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DroidScript Image control allows you to set the pixel data using a base64 string, so you could send the data to a hidden or visible image control and then use the img.Save() method to save it as a jpeg or png.

This is the prototype for the img.SetPixelData method:-

SetPixelData( data, width, height, options )

It can handle with or without mime type header and you can leave out the width, height and options params if you like

Comment: Could you please provide a working sample because I've been struggling with this issue for a very long time

Comment: @JohnManning posted sample code on the answers, can't fit it through the comments, enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of hack to it, you have to use webview in order to view the base64 one, here's the sample code:

```
var temporaryFile = "/sdcard/temp.png";

//Called when application is started.
function OnStart()
{
    //Create a layout with objects vertically centered.
    lay = app.CreateLayout( "linear", "VCenter,FillXY" );   

    //Create a text label and add it to layout.
    txt = app.CreateText( "Hello" );
    txt.SetTextSize( 32 );
    lay.AddChild( txt );

    btn= app.CreateButton("Choose Image");
    btn.SetOnTouch(function(){
        app.ChooseImage("Internal", function(path){
            var img2 = app.CreateImage(path);
            var img2 = app.CreateImage(path);
            var img = app.CreateImage(null, 0.3, 0.3);
            img.DrawImage(img2,0,0,1,1);
            img.Save(temporaryFile);
            txt = app.ReadFile(temporaryFile,'base64');
            var pixelData = 'data:image/png;base64,' + txt;
            var converted = base64Image(pixelData, 0.3, 0.3);

            lay.AddChild(app.CreateText("raw"));
            lay.AddChild(img2);
            lay.AddChild(app.CreateText("modified"));
            lay.AddChild(img);
            lay.AddChild(app.CreateText("base64 src"));
            lay.AddChild(converted);
        });
    });
    lay.AddChild( btn );

    //Add layout to app.    
    app.AddLayout( lay );
}

function base64Image(src, w, h)
{
    var web = app.CreateWebView(w,h);
    var html = [
        "<body style='margin:0px'>",
        "<img src='"+src+"' width='100%' height='100%'/>",
        "</body>"
    ].join('');
    web.LoadHtml(html, "file:///Sys/");
    return web;
}
```